# Android Multiple Threads in Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I want to run multiple threads in service. Like in google doc example:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> However, because you handle each call to onStartCommand() yourself,
>   you can perform multiple requests simultaneously. That's not what this
>   example does, but if that's what you want, then you can create a new
>   thread for each request and run them right away (instead of waiting
>   for the previous request to finish).

How I can perform multiple request simultaneously?

For example I want 10 threads that starts depend on Message.what.

How and where to create this 10 thread? In `OnCreate` in service?

But `OnCreate` exec only once when I create service. But if I want to add threads to service `dynamically` and `generate message` depends on `intent extras`? For example:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
intent1.putExtra("what", 1);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
intent2.putExtra("what", 2);
...
startService(intent1);
startService(intent2);
...
```

And I should to create 10 handlers and 10 looper for each threads?

Thank You!

Comment: If your need to react on every `startService` call you can use `onStartCommand`. `onCreate` is called only once. It's quite unclear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Multiple requests means network calls?

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed, I mean this: I receive request from network to send contacts and send them in service, while sending contacts I receive request to send file and I want to use the same service with different thread to sent this file, while sending contacts and files another request can come and so on. (Sorry for the late reply, but I do not have any notification email about comments and answers).

Answer (score 1):

> How I can perform multiple request simultaneously?

Use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), configured for a reasonable number of threads (e.g., 2 times the number of cores, plus 1).

> How and where to create this 10 thread? In OnCreate in service?

You can set up the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in `onCreate()`, or possibly just in a field initializer.

> But OnCreate exec only once when I create service.

Which is why you use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and configure it for an appropriate number of threads.

> But if I want to add threads to service dynamically and generate message depends on intent extras?

Just call `submit()` in `onStartCommand()` to add a piece of work to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If there is an available thread, the work will run right away. If not, you supply a work queue to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and your submitted work will await a free thread.

Comment: Thank You for answer I will try this (and thanks for nice book)!

Comment: @CommonsWare could you past simple example for how can i use that on service?